# Solr Replicas Usually Recovering and Recovered Faild

Tags: solr, search-engine, solrcloud

I have deployed a `SolrCloud` in AKS with 5 Nodes, each Node with 32Gb RAM. In Solr, I create a collection with 7 shards and 3 replicas. Usually, my pod is restarted. So I can see replicas to recovering and recovered failed. I checked the log and nothing.

What can I do to fix that?

I try to set `autocommit` with 5 min and 10 min. However, it does not work well.

I have a Statefulset solr with 5 replicas. Each replica requests 20Gi - 2 CPU and limits 32Gi - 4 CPU. I set JAVA_MEM with xms12g; xmx16g and each replica are on a node of Kubernetes. Sometimes, I see one or two solr pods restarts. So replicas on a shard will usually go from active to recovering and finally recovered failed.

Comment: Not easy to help you without more information.
Can you please provide the dataset size, the Solr node configuration, the Kubernetes pod configuration, logs, and everything else you can think can be useful for debugging

Comment: I have a Statefulset solr with 5 replicas. Each replica requests 20Gi - 2 CPU and limits 32Gi - 4 CPU. I set JAVA_MEM with xms12g; xmx16g and each replica are on a node of Kubernetes. Sometimes, I see one or two solr pods restarts. So replicas on a shard will usually go from active to recovering and finally recovered failed.